# c# list of objects to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have the next object:

public partial class PEDIDOS

{

```
public PEDIDOS()
{
    this.ARTICULOS = new HashSet<ARTICULOS>();
}
public int id { get; set; }
public string descripcion { get; set; }
public PROVEEDORES PROVEEDORES { get; set; }
```

}

And the class PROVEEDORES:

```
public partial class PROVEEDORES
    {
    public PROVEEDORES()
    {
        this.PEDIDOS = new HashSet<PEDIDOS>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string codProveedor { get; set; }

}
```

And I Have a LIST of PEDIDOS.

I want to show this this list in a datagridview (windows forms):

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;
```

Then I get this:

```
|id | descrpcion | PROVEEDORES                    |
--------------------------------------------------|
|1  | EXAMPLE    | system.data.dinamicproxyes.....|
|2  | example    | system.data.dinamicproxyes.....|
...
```

But I need that proveedores column, was the "nombre" field of PROVEEDORES's class:

```
|id | descrpcion | PROVEEDORES                    |
--------------------------------------------------|
|1  | EXAMPLE    | proveedor's name               |
|2  | example    | proveedor's name               |
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lista this way:

```
var lista=  context.PEDIDOS.Select( i=>  new {
id=i.id,
description=i.description,
PROVEEDORES=i.ROVEEDORES.nombre
}).ToList();

....
dataGridView1.DataSource = lista;
```

Comment: thanks, it was a perfect solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you describe is to override the `PROVEEDORES` `ToString` method. Something like…

```
public override string ToString() {
  return nombre;
}
```